# ActionBarSherlock theming of the items

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

[image: Example of the action bar]

I receive task to implement such action bar in the android application as is presented above. For solving this issue i decide to use action bar sherlock. I solve issue how to set background and set actin bar items. 
So the main question is.How i should implement theming of the action bar items to be like on the image?With such border style and action background.

Comment: So just to make sure: You want to know how to make the alarm-timer-settings button in the actionbarsherlock? You know how to do the theming.

Comment: I want to know how implement right theming to receive such borders and action background of the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solving this issue i decide to use additional layout, it was for me much more easier than theming of the Sherlock ActionBar.